# Laravel parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE

Tags: laravel-5

After installing laravel we get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\index.php on line 50

Comment: I still have this problem, and we cannot put our laravel application live.  We are using php 5.6.  for apache and for command line.  "php -v" gives "5.6"

Comment: Did you create key?

Answer (score 46):

Laravel 5.1 uses the [`::class` property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) to get string representations of a fully qualified classname. The error you're seeing is caused by [this line](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8914be5fc864ebc6877be38ff3502997e0c62761/public/index.php#L52)

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

This language feature has been introduced in PHP 5.5 which is a requirement of Laravel 5.1. Your installed PHP version is probably older than 5.5. Try to update your PHP binary.

---

In case you are interested in why `::class` is used, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801452/1903366)

Comment: I am using php 5.6.0, but still i am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\wamp\www\laravelmaster\public\index.php on line 50` , i checked from cmd like `php -v` and using laravel 5.2

Comment: @151291 Your CLI version of php (the one you get with `php -v`) might be different from the one the webserver uses. Put `phpinfo()` in a PHP file and open it in your browser. There you should see the actual version your server uses...

Comment: Hi, My CLI version as well as version of PHP showing in phpinfo is 7.1.22 but still I am getting same error. Can you please help? why I am getting this error still? Thanks

Comment: @Dhirender - I know this is old, but for others, this error also happens for me when I forget a `;` after a `use` statement for a class I'm adding referencing in a class.

Answer (score 7):

Same thing happened to me also. I found that web server was using my old PHP version 5. To solve it for me, I did this -

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This was my issue, and `php -v` on the command line was using 7.1 but the server was still on php5

Comment: Hi, My CLI version as well as version of PHP showing in phpinfo is 7.1.22 but still I am getting same error. Can you please help? why I am getting this error still? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your php version is too low. 
Try version 7.0 or later php.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP version on your Xampp is lower than 5.5.9 as specified in the [Laravel 5.1 doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation).

Simply uninstall your current Xampp software and download a fresh copy  at Apache website with this specification [5.6.12 / PHP 5.6.12](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) .

Do not forget to collaborate with your host provider to ensure that your hosting account runs the required PHP version (>=5.5.9) during the deployment of your  Laravel 5.1 app online.

Comment: Yeah version might cause that too. But make sure you get version actuallyorking on your server, virtual machine or whatever you are using

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error but error was in app/User.php line 10.
Actually, line 10 was ok but before line 10 I was missing some php syntax.

After correct the php syntax error It was fixed. So you have to check C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\index.php on line 49 carefully I am sure there is something wrong. Just try to correct. It will be fixed.