# How to use class_exists correctly in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, class, php-5.4, fpdi

I'm using an old system with PHP 5.4 that I can't upgrade. I had to make a small change by adding a library for PDF file generation called FPDF/FPDI that has this function:

```
protected function getPdfParserInstance(StreamReader $streamReader)
{
    /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
    if (\class_exists(FpdiPdfParser::class)) {
        /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
        return new FpdiPdfParser($streamReader);
    }

    return new PdfParser($streamReader);
}
```

The problem is that `::class` was added in PHP 5.5 as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205590/laravel-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-class-expecting-t-string-or-t-v).

The question is: what changes need to be made to this function to work in PHP 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::class` just evaluates to the string containing the class' full name, so use that instead. Looking at the [top of the file](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/blob/master/src/FpdiTrait.php#L37) for the `use` statements, you'll find that `FpdiPdfParser` is just an alias, so your code should be rewritten to look like this:

```
if (class_exists("setasign\\FpdiPdfParser\\PdfParser\\PdfParser"))
```

You don't, strictly speaking, need to escape the backslashes; few [escape sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) contain capital letters, but it's good practice to do so anyway.

It's unlikely this will be the only compatibility issues you'll come across. If a system can run PHP 5.4, it can almost certainly run PHP 5.6 which is only a couple of years out of date.

Comment: The problem is I can't upgrade ('others' have to and 'others' don't want). Thanks!